# Rails: Embedding URL within Image Tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, href, embedded-ruby

I have the following in my html.erb file:

```
<%= image_tag "logo.jpg", :class => "img-responsive", :href =>"http://www.google.com" %>
```

However, this is not a clickable link. I assumed the :href = > would make it so. Does anyone have any ideas of making your rails image a clickable link? I tried the following logic which I found on another Stack Overflow Post:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("logo.jpg", :class => "img-responsive"), "http://wwww.google.com" %>
```

But this makes the image smaller and adds an odd half circle at the bottom of the image. I also cannot add `:style` or `:class` working properly.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could just wrap the image tag with regular anchor tags:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <%= image_tag "logo.jpg", :class => "img-responsive" %>
</a>
```

Comment: That gave me the same result as last time, check the updated post.

Comment: which result?  the image being smaller or the link not being clickable

Answer (score 0):

The second way is technically the right way to do it, however since its giving you issues could always try this:

```
<%= link_to 'http://google.com' do %>
    <%= image_tag 'logo.jpg', class: 'img-responsive' %>
<% end %>
```

As for the class/style not adding properly I've always done it as

```
class: 'this-is-a-class'
```

and

```
style: 'padding-left:30px;'
```